# Unable to debbug R code on VSC running on Windows

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I have installed the following extensions to VSC running on Windows: R, R Debugger, and R Tools, nevertheless, when I try to debug some R code, I get this message: `Please install the R package: "vscDebugger"`.

I have tried to install it using `install.packages("vscDebugger", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")`, but it failed.

This is my *launch.json*:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "R-Debugger",
            "name": "Launch R-Workspace",
            "request": "launch",
            "debugMode": "workspace",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "R-Debugger",
            "name": "Debug R-File",
            "request": "launch",
            "debugMode": "file",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "file": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "R-Debugger",
            "name": "Debug R-Function",
            "request": "launch",
            "debugMode": "function",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "file": "${file}",
            "mainFunction": "main",
            "allowGlobalDebugging": false
        },
        {
            "type": "R-Debugger",
            "name": "Debug R-Package",
            "request": "launch",
            "debugMode": "workspace",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "includePackageScopes": true,
            "loadPackages": [
                "."
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "R-Debugger",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to R process",
            "splitOverwrittenOutput": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the error with all options.

Answer (score 10):

The answer posted by @HuLu is not a correct answer as it uses his own R and vscode locations, the real solution to this problem comes from the R Debugger extension itself.

In the error description it states:

> This extension is under development, you should try the command r.debugger.updateRPackage

So, now if the vscDebugger does not show up and you get an error when installing manually, try:

```
@command:
r.debugger.updateRPackage
```

Or the command:

```
Ctrl + Shift + P
R Debugger: Update or install the required R Package
```

When selecting this option, a very similar command to the mentioned by @HuLu gets executed.

Comment: where should we put `@command: r.debugger.updateRPackage`? I tried in command palette but that did not work.

Comment: Try re installing the extension, the command gets executed when using command palette.  Or try copying and pasting HuLu's command and changing your vscode and R absolute paths.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I'm trying your solution now, but I'm getting this error: `cannot open URL 'https://github.com/ManuelHentschel/VSCode-R-Debugger/releases/download/v0.5.3/vscDebugger_0.5.3.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'`

Comment: Hey. It seems like the VSCode R Debugger had an update on 15/05/2023 version 0.5.3 was just releaased. Try uninstalling and installing the extension again.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the solution was to execute this command: `"\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\R.exe" --no-restore --quiet -f "c:\Users\hugo.villalobos\.vscode\extensions\rdebugger.r-debugger-0.4.7\R\install.R" --args "https://github.com/ManuelHentschel/VSCode-R-Debugger/releases/download/v0.4.7/vscDebugger_0.4.7.zip"`

Comment: This did work for me. However, as of October 23, the vscDebugger package version and the rdebugger version are not synced.